# Subscription in IOS

Tags: ios, in-app-purchase

I have a confusion regarding subscription in the app. I want to upload my app to the app store with some price tier. I want user to pay every month some subscription fee to use complete functionality of the app. I have seen apps that are available as free with subscription but my app will be paid with subscription.

Will Apple reject my app?

I have already asked this question on Apple developer forum. Here is the link:
https://discussions.apple.com/thread/5134928

Answer (score 3):

Looking at the [App Store Review Guidelines](https://developer.apple.com/appstore/resources/approval/guidelines.html), the only rule I see that could affect you is:

> 11.15 Apps may only use auto renewing subscriptions for periodicals (newspapers, magazines), business Apps (enterprise, productivity,
>   professional creative, cloud storage) and media Apps (video, audio,
>   voice), or the App will be rejected.

I guess you have to determine if you app fits in one of these categories. I always say that Apple can do whatever they want, so the only 100% way to know if you'll be rejected is to submit it. The review process is much faster than it used to be, so it shouldn't set you back more than a week.

**Other subscription-related rules**

> 11.6 Content subscriptions using IAP must last a minimum of 7 days and be available to the user from all of their iOS devices

That's a straightforward rule.

> 11.12 Apps offering subscriptions must do so using IAP, Apple will share the same 70/30 revenue split with developers for these
>   purchases, as set forth in the Developer Program License Agreement.

If you want someone to subscribe within the app, you have to give Apple their cut by using IAP. Otherwise, you need your own website for sign-up, à la Netflix.

> 11.13 Apps that link to external mechanisms for purchases or subscriptions to be used in the App, such as a “buy” button that goes
>   to a web site to purchase a digital book, will be rejected

When you set up your own website for sign-ups, you can't even link to it. People have to know about it before using your app.